# convert image to spritesheet of tiles for isometric map?

Tags: java, tiles, tilemap, isometric

is there a way to convert an isometric image (like the first image) to a spritesheet (like the second image), in order to place each image on the isometric map with the code?

The map looks like the first image, but some buildings are bigger than just one tile, so I need several squares (let's say the first image is a building, made of multiple tiles with different colors), and each square is placed with an offset of 64x32. The building is created in Blender and I save the image with the isometric perspective. But I have to split each square from this image in order to have the spritesheet, maybe there is smarter way, or a java software that would make the conversion for me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

First get all the 128 x 64 rectangles with each tile by iterating through the big image and taking subimages.

Then, use an alpha map to keep only the tile you are trying to separate. If you don't know what an alpha map is, there should be plenty of tutorials online explaining how to use them.